# Getting started with text analysis, making a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, text-analysis

I am doing text analysis in R. Thus far, I have a vector that contains the corpus and metadata in a csv that I would like to merge with it. Here is how I obtain the corpus in vector form

```
corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(alldocs)) # corpus is a vector
```

Here is the metadata:

```
metadata <- read.csv("alldocs.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings = c(""), sep = ",")
```

How can I combine the two? I want to combine them in order (*i.e.*, first document in corpus corresponds to first row in *csv*, *etc.*). In the end, I want a dataframe where each row corresponds to the right document from the corpus.

**Update**:
I was told to try to make the problem reproducible.

I started with a folder with all the texts I have. I start by loading them into a vector:

```
alldocs <- Corpus(
  DirSource("/path/file/wheredocumentsare"),
  readerControl = list(reader = readPlain, language = "en", load = FALSE)
)

corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(alldocs)) # corpus is a vector
metadata <- read.csv("metadata.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings = c(""), sep = ",")
```

I would like to combine metadata and corpus.Yet when I input,

```
fulldata <- data.frame(corpus, metadata)
```

I get the following error message

> `Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : cannot coerce class "c("VCorpus", "Corpus")" to a data.frame`

Comment: `data.frame(corpus,metadata)` ?

Comment: If I try "data.frame(corpus,metadata)",                                                            
                                                                                                                        I get the error message:  Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class "c("VCorpus", "Corpus")" to a data.frame"

Comment: Welcome to SO, Ronald. Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post. You can use dput() to write small portions of the documents file and metadata and add them to your post to make the problem reproducible.

Comment: Look in the documentation of the tm package and check the help file under `meta` or `DublinCore` for meta data management of the Corpus